# Как нарисовать карту, нанести на нее точки (маркеры) и анимировать всплывающие подсказки (tooltip) при наведении?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css3, svg, координаты

У меня есть следующее изображение карты:

[image: Карта]

**Задача:** Мне необходимо нарисовать такую карту средствами и технологиями, которыми это выполнить возможно, и нанести на нее точки (маркеры), обозначающие города. Кроме этого, при клике на маркеры должны появляться всплывающие подсказки (tooltip) с названиями городов.

1. Если воспроизвести (нарисовать) карту с помощью кода невозможно, то допустимо использовать ее изображение. Это реализовать можно двумя способами: использовать ее как фоновое изображение, применив свойство `background` или вставить ее как файл с картинкой, используя тег `<img>`, задав адрес файла через атрибут `src`.

Вариант с `background`:

```css
div {
  width: 800px;
  height: 506px;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfnZ.jpg);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Вариант с использованием тега `<img>`:

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfnZ.jpg">
```

2. Необходимо выставить на этой карте по координатам точки (маркеры), обозначающие города. Каким образом возможно это сделать?

Вот код маркера:

```css
span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  margin: 30px auto;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: red;
  animation: animate 1.5s infinite normal ease-out;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {
    transform: scale(0);
    opacity: .5
  }
  to {
    transform: scale(2);
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<span></span>
```

Вот перечень городов:

```html
<p>Севастополь</p>
<p>Симферополь</p>
<p>Евпатория</p>
<p>Феодосия</p>
<p>Керчь</p>
<p>Ялта</p>
```

3. При клике на маркеры должны появляться всплывающие подсказки (tooltip) с названиями городов. Каким образом возможно это сделать? Такая всплывающая подсказка должна выглядеть, например (ее форма, цвет, размер большого значения не имеют), следующим образом:

[image: Подсказка]

Решить поставленную задачу предлагается любыми средствами и с помощью любых технологий, которые указаны в метках вопроса. Особенно приветствуется подробное описание вашей реализации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вот что должно получиться в итоге:

[**Jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/cf8ubkox/)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**#1 Всплывающие подсказки**

```
<g>
<title>Джанкойский район
  Площадь, км. кв.  - 2 666,96      
  Население, чел. - 64 808
</title>
</g>
```

Если навести курсор на объект, то после некоторого времени появится системный `tooltip` SVG с текстом, который добавлен между тегами  `<title>`

**#2. Маркеры для городов**

Ниже код для Джанкойского района, в который в качестве маркера добавлена окружность и название города

```css
 .state {
    stroke: dodgerblue;
    transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 transition:  1s;
  }
 
 text{
 font-size:24px;
 fill:black;
 }
 
 circle{
 fill:gold;
 stroke:red;
 stroke-width:3; 
 }
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0" y="0" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 1697.6 1072.6">
  <g>
           <title>Джанкойский район
           Площадь, км. кв.  - 2 666,96     
           Население, чел. - 64 808 </title>
          <path class="state" id="Джанкойский район" fill="#FFD6AA" d="M669 176h-2l-1-1v-3-2l-1-4-7-7c-2-2-5-5-5-8v-2l2-2 4-2c3-4 4-8 4-12l-1-12-1-5-3-3-6-3-4-3-1-3 3-8 5 6 20 17 8 8 7 7 1 4c1 3-2 7-2 12l1 6 7 8c2 2 5 4 9 4l2-1 3-2 1-12c0-13-3-27-12-35l-6-4-5-2c-3-2-7-6-10-11 10 3 23 7 30 12 3 2 4 4 5 6 2 3 2 7 2 11 0 5 0 9 2 14l2 5 2 1 3 1 2-1 2-3a37 37 0 001-20l-2-5-1-1 1-2 4-4 4-2 1 4-1 11c0 2 0 5 2 7 2 5 6 7 9 7l10 2h2l2-2 2-16a65 65 0 012-10 4 4 0 011-1l2-1 4 2 7 10 3 6h-1l-3 3-2 4-1 4 1 3c2 2 3 3 5 3l4 1h1a6 6 0 003-1v1l1 2 2 3 8 7-4 3a76 76 0 01-19 9c-2 0-3 1-3 3v1c0 4 1 9 4 13 4 4 8 6 13 6 7 0 13-3 16-9l4-8 5-2h4v2l-2 6-2 8v1l1 11v3l-1 3-1 5 2 5 4 1 5-2c5-3 11-10 17-17l7-9 4-5 7-2 3-2 1-5v-5c-1-8-5-17-5-25 6 4 13 10 17 16s9 14 9 20v2c-1 4-4 8-7 11l-12 8-8 3c-3 1-5 3-7 6v6l1 1-10 4-8 8-4 5-4 4h-12l-6 1-2 2-1 4v3l2 3a49 49 0 006 7l2 1c3 2 5 2 8 2 6 0 11-2 16-4s10-4 14-4a3 3 0 002-5v-1c9-12 21-25 32-35 6-5 12-7 19-9l1 1c-3 1-6 3-8 6-2 4-3 8-3 13l1 10c0 2 1 3 3 3h2l16-1h9l2 4 2 6 2 2a21 21 0 009 3l-7 9-13 12-5 4-10 8c-3 3-6 7-7 11l1 1c0 2 1 3 3 3 12 0 26-2 37-6 4-1 7-3 9-5l8-5a26 26 0 0113-2l-5 8c-2 4-6 8-6 14l2 3v9l-7 9c-1 3-5 6-6 11l-1 2 2 6a56 56 0 01-14 0c-4 0-7-2-11-3l-4-1c-3 0-5 1-7 3l-2 6 2 8c3 3 7 4 10 4h9c6 1 9 2 13 5l-7 5a40 40 0 01-20 3l-2-1-4-1h-1l-3 2-2 3-4 5c-4 4-6 5-9 5l-10-2-13-2c-3 0-7 1-9 4-3 3-4 6-5 10l-1 6-1 5-2 1h-1l-1 1c-4-1-8-4-11-6l-7-8c-2-2-5-2-7-2l-7-1c-4 0-6-1-7-2s-2-2-2-6l-1-1-2-1c-4 0-9 4-13 7-5 3-9 6-13 6a73 73 0 01-29-10l-1-1h-1l-9 6c-2 3-5 5-7 5s-3-1-3-2l-1-5 1-7 2-15-1-7c-1-4-4-6-7-8l-10-3-6-2c-2 0-4 1-5 3-2 1-2 4-3 6l-2 7-6 2-4 3-2 3-1 3h-1l-2-1-1-4 1-12-1-1a97 97 0 01-16-5l-1-1 1-5-1-1-8-3-3-1-1-1v-1l1-2 1-1v-1l1-1 3-5c2-3 4-4 6-5 2-2 5-3 6-6l2-7c-1-6-5-11-5-17l-1-3 1-9c0-3 0-5-2-8l6-3c2-2 5-4 5-7l-1-3-3-3-3-2-1-4-1-6-5-5 1-1c0-5 0-9 2-12s3-7 7-10l10-2c4 0 7 0 11-2l1-2c-3-7-8-15-14-19l-1-1h-1-1l-2-3c-3-4-5-6-5-10v-3l-1-3-2-1z"  />
                 <g transform="translate(-850,-150)">
                     <text x="1580" y="370">Джанкой</text> 
                     <circle cx="1610" cy="400" r="15" />
                </g> 
            </g> 
</svg>
```

**#3. Увеличение региона при наведении**

```
document.querySelectorAll('path.state').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
 const paths = [...document.querySelectorAll('path.state')]
 setTimeout(()=> {
 paths[paths.length - 1].classList.add('scaled');    
 },20)
 
  });
}); 
document.querySelectorAll('path.state').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
 path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
 const paths = [...document.querySelectorAll('path.state')]
 
    setTimeout(()=> {
paths[paths.length - 1].classList.remove('scaled');       
 },20)
  });
});
```

```js
document.querySelectorAll('path.state').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
  path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
 const paths = [...document.querySelectorAll('path.state')]
 setTimeout(()=> {
 paths[paths.length - 1].classList.add('scaled');    
 },20)
 
  });
}); 
document.querySelectorAll('path.state').forEach(path => {
  path.addEventListener('mouseout', e => {
 path.parentNode.parentNode.append(path.parentNode);
 const paths = [...document.querySelectorAll('path.state')]
 
    setTimeout(()=> {
paths[paths.length - 1].classList.remove('scaled');       
 },20)
  });
});
```

```css
.state {
    stroke: dodgerblue;
    transform-origin: center center;
 transform-box: fill-box;
 transition:  1s;
  }
  
  .state.scaled {
 fill:purple;
 stroke:white;
 stroke-width:2px;
   -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
 transform: scale(1.2);
 }
 text{
 font-size:24px;
 fill:black;
 }
 
 circle{
 fill:gold;
 stroke:red;
 stroke-width:3; 
 }
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="map">
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" id="Layer_1" x="0" y="0" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 1697.6 1072.6">
  <g>
           <title>Джанкойский район
           Площадь, км. кв.  - 2 666,96     
           Население, чел. - 64 808 </title>
          <path class="state" id="Джанкойский район" fill="#FFD6AA" d="M669 176h-2l-1-1v-3-2l-1-4-7-7c-2-2-5-5-5-8v-2l2-2 4-2c3-4 4-8 4-12l-1-12-1-5-3-3-6-3-4-3-1-3 3-8 5 6 20 17 8 8 7 7 1 4c1 3-2 7-2 12l1 6 7 8c2 2 5 4 9 4l2-1 3-2 1-12c0-13-3-27-12-35l-6-4-5-2c-3-2-7-6-10-11 10 3 23 7 30 12 3 2 4 4 5 6 2 3 2 7 2 11 0 5 0 9 2 14l2 5 2 1 3 1 2-1 2-3a37 37 0 001-20l-2-5-1-1 1-2 4-4 4-2 1 4-1 11c0 2 0 5 2 7 2 5 6 7 9 7l10 2h2l2-2 2-16a65 65 0 012-10 4 4 0 011-1l2-1 4 2 7 10 3 6h-1l-3 3-2 4-1 4 1 3c2 2 3 3 5 3l4 1h1a6 6 0 003-1v1l1 2 2 3 8 7-4 3a76 76 0 01-19 9c-2 0-3 1-3 3v1c0 4 1 9 4 13 4 4 8 6 13 6 7 0 13-3 16-9l4-8 5-2h4v2l-2 6-2 8v1l1 11v3l-1 3-1 5 2 5 4 1 5-2c5-3 11-10 17-17l7-9 4-5 7-2 3-2 1-5v-5c-1-8-5-17-5-25 6 4 13 10 17 16s9 14 9 20v2c-1 4-4 8-7 11l-12 8-8 3c-3 1-5 3-7 6v6l1 1-10 4-8 8-4 5-4 4h-12l-6 1-2 2-1 4v3l2 3a49 49 0 006 7l2 1c3 2 5 2 8 2 6 0 11-2 16-4s10-4 14-4a3 3 0 002-5v-1c9-12 21-25 32-35 6-5 12-7 19-9l1 1c-3 1-6 3-8 6-2 4-3 8-3 13l1 10c0 2 1 3 3 3h2l16-1h9l2 4 2 6 2 2a21 21 0 009 3l-7 9-13 12-5 4-10 8c-3 3-6 7-7 11l1 1c0 2 1 3 3 3 12 0 26-2 37-6 4-1 7-3 9-5l8-5a26 26 0 0113-2l-5 8c-2 4-6 8-6 14l2 3v9l-7 9c-1 3-5 6-6 11l-1 2 2 6a56 56 0 01-14 0c-4 0-7-2-11-3l-4-1c-3 0-5 1-7 3l-2 6 2 8c3 3 7 4 10 4h9c6 1 9 2 13 5l-7 5a40 40 0 01-20 3l-2-1-4-1h-1l-3 2-2 3-4 5c-4 4-6 5-9 5l-10-2-13-2c-3 0-7 1-9 4-3 3-4 6-5 10l-1 6-1 5-2 1h-1l-1 1c-4-1-8-4-11-6l-7-8c-2-2-5-2-7-2l-7-1c-4 0-6-1-7-2s-2-2-2-6l-1-1-2-1c-4 0-9 4-13 7-5 3-9 6-13 6a73 73 0 01-29-10l-1-1h-1l-9 6c-2 3-5 5-7 5s-3-1-3-2l-1-5 1-7 2-15-1-7c-1-4-4-6-7-8l-10-3-6-2c-2 0-4 1-5 3-2 1-2 4-3 6l-2 7-6 2-4 3-2 3-1 3h-1l-2-1-1-4 1-12-1-1a97 97 0 01-16-5l-1-1 1-5-1-1-8-3-3-1-1-1v-1l1-2 1-1v-1l1-1 3-5c2-3 4-4 6-5 2-2 5-3 6-6l2-7c-1-6-5-11-5-17l-1-3 1-9c0-3 0-5-2-8l6-3c2-2 5-4 5-7l-1-3-3-3-3-2-1-4-1-6-5-5 1-1c0-5 0-9 2-12s3-7 7-10l10-2c4 0 7 0 11-2l1-2c-3-7-8-15-14-19l-1-1h-1-1l-2-3c-3-4-5-6-5-10v-3l-1-3-2-1z"  />
                 <g transform="translate(-850,-150)">
                     <text x="1580" y="370">Джанкой</text> 
                     <circle cx="1610" cy="400" r="15" />
                </g> 
            </g> 
</svg>
```

Полный код:  [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Alexandr_T/full/OJWQrNX)

Хоть мне и удалось оптимизировать исходник с 477k ==> 25k Всё таки в сниппет код не поместился

Comment: @Sevastopol' Благодарю, c ripple маркерами решил не заморачиваться, всё пытался впихнуть код в сниппет, все равно не влезло - 36.000 вместо дозволенных 30.000 символов

Answer (score 1):

Карту вставил как файл с картинкой, используя тег `<img>`, задав адрес файла через атрибут `src`.

Точки (маркеры), обозначающие города, выставил на карте способом абсолютного позиционирования относительно изображения карты с помощью свойства `position` и значения `absolute`.

Появление всплывающих подсказок (tooltip) с названиями городов реализовал с помощью наведения на маркер курсора мыши, используя псевдокласс `:hover`.

```css
div {
  position: relative; width: 800px; height: 506px;
}

span {
  display: block; position: absolute; width: 10px; height: 10px;
  background-color: gold; border-radius: 10px; cursor: pointer;
}

span:hover::before {
  content: ""; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; width: 30px; height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px; background-color: gold;
  animation: animate 1.5s infinite normal ease-out;
}

@keyframes animate {
  from {transform: scale(0); opacity: .5}
  to {transform: scale(2); opacity: 0;}
}

.aa {top: 440px; left: 220px;}
.bb {top: 320px; left: 360px;}
.cc {top: 260px; left: 170px;}
.dd {top: 320px; left: 545px;}
.ee {top: 220px; left: 750px;}
.ff {top: 453px; left: 333px;}

i {
  display: block; position: absolute; left: 5px; bottom: 5px;
  background: gold; padding: 1px 5px;
  border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 2px;
  font-style: normal; font-size: 14px; font-family: monospace;
  opacity: 0;
  transform: rotate( -90deg) scale(0);
  transform-origin: 5px bottom;
  transition: all .15s ease-out;
}
span:hover i {opacity: 1; transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1);}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lfnZ.jpg">
  <span class="aa"><i>Севастополь</i></span>
  <span class="bb"><i>Симферополь</i></span>
  <span class="cc"><i>Евпатория</i></span>
  <span class="dd"><i>Феодосия</i></span>
  <span class="ee"><i>Керчь</i></span>
  <span class="ff"><i>Ялта</i></span>
</div>
```

Comment: а вариант SVG карты у вас есть? так как было бы интересней сделать всплывающие подсказки с одновременным увеличением региона. Можно взять другую карту SVG или обязательно нужно использовать вашу карту

Comment: да забрал, файл жуть, пол мегабайта, это-то в текстовом формате

Comment: оптимизировал файл стал 77k